# How do I start GWT devmode on a particular port from the console?

Tags: python, gwt, ant

So, within the directory containing my GWT application, I can type in the console

> ant devmode

And it will start up my GWT application as per usual. So far so good.

However, what if wish to specify the port as a dynamic argument when starting devmode. Something conceptually like:

> ant devmode port=8821

Or am I supposed to pass in some system variable to GWT? What is the convention for this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing an argument via ant can be done via the ant properties. The call would be:

```
ant devmode -Dport=8821
```

In your ant file specify a property port. The default value will be overridden when you pass the argument via the command line:

```
<property name="port" value="8080" />  //replace 8080 with the default value you want.
```

And in the ant location where you want to use the property, use it as follows:

```
<arg value="-port"/>
<arg value="${port}"/>
```

Update: fixed syntax, as suggested by Stephen, of property to make this example correct.

Comment: Seems to work smashingly. Only change I had to make is that 
<property name="port" value="8080">
should be
<property name="port" value="8080"/>

Thank you